# About USB-C Dongles and Hubs

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, displayport

I'm looking to get a USB-C Hub like the one in the image, there are several of those.

[image: USB Hub]

What I understand is that all of these hubs, no matter the brand, they take out 2 USB-C in exchange for 2 USB Type-C and several USB Type-A and SD Card slots, etc.

The little Lightning icon means that it is the port used to charge the MacBook... but my question is this:

Can the **other** USB-C (not the one with the lightning icon) be used to send video to an external display? Example: With a USB-C to DisplayPort cable (not 4K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the product description at Amazon for [Lenovo USB C Hub, Aluminum Type C Hub Adapter for MacBook Pro 13" and 15" 2016/2017, Thunderbolt 3 Port, USB-C Port, SD and Micro SD/TF Card Reader and 2 USB 3.0 Ports, Grey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07545BQZQ) it states:

> The Thunderbolt 3 USB-C port supports data transfer, video output, and charging while the standard USB-C port only supports data transfer and does not support USB-C video output or USB-C charging.

BTW The port with the lighting icon is the port referenced in what's quoted above.

Other mentioned product description/specifications include:

> - Color:Grey
> - This 6-in-1 Lenovo USB Type-C Hub expands your 2016/2017 MacBook Pro capabilities while on-the-go.
> - This adapter only applies to 2016/2017 MacBook Pro 13‘’and 15‘’.
> - Only one hub is included, power adapters, SD/TF memory cards, cables or other accessories are not included.
> - The Thunderbolt 3 USB-C port supports data transfer, video output, and charging while the standard USB-C port only supports data transfer
>     and does not support USB-C video output or USB-C charging.
> - Compatible displays and cables are required to achieve maximum video resolution.
> - One USB-A port supports a charging output of up to DC5V/900mAh and two USB-A ports support a total charging output of DC5V/1.5A. USB-A
>     port is not recommended for charging.
> - SD and TF card slots can be used simultaneously.
> - Specifications:
> - Brand: Lenovo
> - Product Type:USB C Hub
> - Model: C608
> - Interface:USB 3.0 Type-A port，Thunderbolt 3 USB-C port，Standard USB-C port，SD/TF card slot
> - Tips
> - For best performance, devices connected to this hub should not exceed total current of 900mA maximum. Otherwise, output current may
>     become unstable or disconnected.
> - Below devices are often rated as follows for your reference:
> - Mouse: 100mAPortable hard disk: Max. 500mA
> - USB 3.0 portable hard disk: Max. 900mA
> - Keyboard: Max. 500mA
>
> Please double check the current of your devices before connecting to
>   the hub.